# Horizontal scrolling sticky section with Locomotive scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sticky

Looking to create a horizontal scrolling section inside a sticky div with the following structure using Locomotive scroll framework (https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll). My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="sec01" class="the-height-400vh-section"><!-- this has the same height as does the 400vh width, timing should match -->
    <div class="the-sticky-div" id="sticky"  data-scroll data-scroll-sticky data-scroll-target="#sec01"><!-- this is stickying to viewport while we scroll -->
        <div class="the-overflow-hidden-mask">
            <div class="the-width-400vh-scrollable-div" data-scroll data-scroll-direction="horizontal" data-scroll-speed="12" data-scroll-target="#sec01"><!-- we're scrolling this 400vh to the right while we're scrolling the 400vh height of the parent -->
                <div class="the-content">
                    <div class="a-block"></div>
                    <div class="a-block"></div>
                    <div class="a-block"></div>
                    <div class="a-block"></div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS is applied:

```
.the-sticky-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
  z-index: 1;
}
.the-overflow-hidden-mask {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 200;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
.the-height-400vh-section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 400vh;
  margin-left: 0px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 60px none rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.09);
  background-color: #fff;
}

.the-width-400vh-scrollable-div {
  display: flex;
  width: 400vh;
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  will-change: transform;
}
.the-content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10vh;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
  .a-block {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    left:0;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 87.1%, 0.72);
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px 8px rgba(205, 43, 177, 0.25);
  }
}
```

The logic behind this should be as follows:

[image]

**But I have two main issues:**

- the horizontal scroll initialises too early
- the horizontal content slides in from right and is not in the initial position to start scrolling.

Any ideas what could be done with the current solution to achieve a similar end result to i.e www.reformcollective.com (sections enter screen, scrolling starts, scrolling ends when last section is viewed).

Thanks in advance

Comment: width: 400vh; vh - means vertical height, should be 400vw, which is vertical width

Answer (score 4):

You do not need Locomotive Scroll just [20 lines of vanilla JS](https://codepen.io/KhaledPen/pen/YzXeXLm).

You need three containers which we can refer to as:

1. space holder - This container will maintain the vertical space scroll space. More on this below.
2. sticky - This container will have a set height (`100vh` in my example). It will also be `position: sticky; top: 0;`.
3. horizontal - This container will contain the content that you wish to horizontally scroll on. Its width will be determined by the content that it contains.

To achieve the desired effect you must set the height of "space holder" to the width of "horizontal". Then on scroll you must horizontally translate "horizontal" equal to the offset top of "sticky".

Check out my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60627759/13042187).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25572972)

Comment: @Andreas sorry didn't know. I edited the answer to include the essential parts

Comment: Rather than copying and pasting the same answer, you can mark it as a duplicate to the similar question that you are referring to

Comment: @Andreas I actually can't I would need 15 reputation according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). Out of curiosity wouldn't marking a question as a duplicate give us the same problem as just providing a link? Either way the user doesn't get their question answered unless they go look at that alternate answer

Comment: Then you should simply wait. No, marking a question as duplicate does not give the same problem since it refers the established answer from the community. Then if the question turns out to be not a duplicate, the user can edit their question to show how it is not a duplicate

Comment: Possibly a great solution, although since the rest of the site is heavily depending on the functionalities that the questions was in respect to it is uncertain if this will work and should be tested with Locomotive scroll functionalities

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on exactly the same thing for a project.

The offset seems to be caused by the data-scroll-speed. The higher the speed the more offset it is off to the right of the screen.

I am currently experimenting with data-scroll-position="top" on the "the-width-400vh-scrollable-div" class in your example.

This approach has the horizontal scrolling div start in the correct position but it immediately starts scrolling from the top of the screen. So therefore only works if your horizontal scrolling div is at the top and not placed further down the page.

Perhaps this will give you some ideas if you haven't solved it already.
If you did figure it out please share your solution. This would be extremely helpful to me and others I'm sure!

Comment: Unfortunately didn't find a bullet proof solution, ended up adjusting a lot for different media queries which ended up being quite risky for unconventional screen sizes. The position top didn't work also as you noted, since the container needed to be in the center of the screen. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'll post my solution when I finally get there...

Answer (score 1):

The way which worked for me:

- get rid of locomotive horizontal scrolling;
- add locomotive on scroll handler so you have current scrolled y position;
- in scroll handler add some math/logic which answers the question:

"how many pixels horizontal section must be translated, knowing the fact that translated distance must remain proportional to vertical pixels scrolled"

- on scroll - translate your horizontal section;

Also keep in mind that viewport is not a square, so distance scrolled vertically is bigger than distance scrolled horizontally.

Basically, I didn't find a way to deal with this problem using locomotive horizontal scrolling.

[image: scheme]