# Horizontal scrolling sticky section

Tags: scroll, sticky, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

On the website I'm building I would like to integrate a horizontal `position: sticky;` scrolling section in the middle of a page. The page has vertical scroll. The user could scroll the section from A to Z with the vertical natural scroll of the page.

I found a perfect example of what I would like to achieve: https://nlkyt.csb.app

I don't find any resources on the subject. Does anyone knows how to create such effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a similar effect when I stumbled upon [this blog post](https://sudo.isl.co/translate-vertical-horizontal/). To sum it up you need three containers which we can refer to as:

1. space holder - This container will maintain the vertical space scroll space. More on this below.
2. sticky - This container will have a set height (`100vh` in my example). It will also be `position: sticky; top: 0;`.
3. horizontal - This container will contain the content that you wish to horizontally scroll on. Its width will be determined by the content that it contains.

To achieve the desired effect you must set the height of "space holder" to the width of "horizontal". Then on scroll you must horizontally translate "horizontal" equal to the offset top of "sticky".

If you're using react then follow the blog post from above. If you want the vanilla javascript version [check out this codepen](https://codepen.io/KhaledPen/pen/YzXeXLm) that I made.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but maybe you know a way to apply sticky scrolling to this?

Comment: @MicasiO Sorry im not sure I understand your request. Can you provide an example site that does what you want?

Comment: Something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/fwcuo