# React table horizontal scroll bar displayed only at end of vertical scroll bar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, user-interface, react-table

I am working on react table .I have got a small issue with the horizontal scroll. When table has a horizontal scroll, the vertical scrollbar is visible only AFTER we scroll horizontally to the end.Is it possible to place a vertical scroll in such way that it will be visible always without need to scroll to it ?

[image]

[image]

[react table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/bootstrap-ui-components)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Horizontal scrolling sticky section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60419944/horizontal-scrolling-sticky-section)

Answer (score 0):

Probably late, but someone else might be having the same issue. This worked for me;
Add a max-height on the .ReactTable and .rt-tbody classes like this:

```
.ReactTable .rt-tbody {
    max-height: 50vh;    //use whatever height is suitable for you.  
    overflow: scroll;
}
```